# Changing color of Eclipse links in quick fix or Eclipse links in preferences on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, colors, hyperlink, gtk

if i use a dark theme then links in Eclipse-"quick fix" or in i.e. Eclipse->Preferences->General->Editor (the three 'see... "File Associaton"|"Content Types"|"Appearance"'-links) are unreadable.

On [this image](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/234/thumbs/5614420315_b.jpg) the links i am talking about are cyan on grey:

I found a solution for Windows/XP:

> The hover uses the same colors as the on your system. On Windows you
>   can change that via Display settings > Appearance > Advanced: ToolTip.
>   The link color is the one used in your browser (IE on Windows).

However, i need a solution for Linux (XFCE 4.8.1/GTK)

I checked/tested all settings of Eclipse and i found no setting for this link-color. It seems to be a system-setting (GTK), so i already tried to add this to gtkrc:

```
style "default" {
        GtkWidget::link-color = "#ffffff"
}

class "GtkWidget" style "default"
```

but this did not change the link color in Eclipse.

I hope you can help - thanks!

Comment: image link is broken :-(

Answer (score 5):

### GNOME

http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/06/eclipse-and-eclipse-based-apps-on-ubuntu-13-04-desktop-hacks/

### KDE

Use the colors menu (the first entry in the picture):

[image]

And redefine the tooltip background color:

[image]

Then enjoy the readable popups:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Install gnome-color-chooser and customize the tooltip color as described here:

http://www.devsniper.com/black-tooltip-in-eclipse-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: Restart Eclipse to see the change

Answer (score 1):

I'll chime in here, since I have the same issue.

There is **no** fix for this, when running Eclipse on Unix (KDE, Gnome, etc).

The color for links, which is used in the QuickFix list as well as various other places in the UI (such as Preferences panels), is hardcoded.

On Windows, you are luckier, since Eclipse uses the native link widget, which takes its colors from system settings.

On non-Windows, you are stuck with a dark-blue hardcoded color.

What it *should* do, at least on GTK, is use the GtkWidget::link-color setting. But it doesn't, currently.

If you want to see it fixed, either upvode this bug or fix the code yourself:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=130444

Sad, I know ):

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse or have a look at the [Eclipse color themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) site.

Comment: First link is broken.