# Change 'fixes' background color in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors

I've been trying to change the background color for the 'quick-fixes' pop-up (the pop up that lists ways to fix an error) in eclipse juno. Currently the color is black and the text is blue which makes it very hard to read.

I cant find the correct way to change the color. Please help. Its really annoying to squint and have to read blue text on a black background.

Comment: Hey buddy did you find the solution? if yes, could you please share it?

Comment: Nope, just using the new Android Studio instead :)

Comment: More info on [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326826/).. sadly nothing awesome :(

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts as well, here is the fix.

- Go to preferences.
- Search for "Annotations"

  ```
  for each Annotation Type:

     if "Text as" == "Highlighted" and Color == black:

         Set the color to light or uncheck "Text As"
  ```

In this screen shot, I am fixing Occurrences.

The problem I show to the left is the "Matching Tags" annotation which had the same problem.

[image: Screen Shot showing Preference Repair]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the text in the pop-up.

In windows you can go Control Panel, search for colors and metrics and then select Change window colors and metrics. In the item menu select Hyperlinks and change the Color.

EDIT: This fix is valid for Windows 7. Windows 10 does not have the option to change Hyperlinks color.

Comment: Seems that in addition to eclipse configuration, it is also dependent from OS config.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click anywhere in the Editor Window, and at the bottom of the context menu select Preferences. This will bring you into `Java -> Editor`. At the bottom ofthat window select the element colors you wish to change, in your case `Parameter hints background` and `Parameter hints background` or `Completion overview background` and `Completion overview foreground`, depending on which one it is you are having a problem with.

Comment: nope that doesnt work. The box background itself is a different color (black). Changing the parameters doesn't do anything. I'll try to upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, I do not think you can change the color. I am not willing to go to Eclipse source code and find it but here's what fixed it for me. Not perfectly but to a level I can use the quick fix. In my case, the background and foreground was same. (Luna, Dark Theme, Using Solarized Editor Theme).

- Go into the Preferences (Window -> Preferences)
- Choose General -> Appearance from the left menu
- Uncheck the checkbox Use mixed fonts and colours for labels

The detail is in this post. [How to change the highlight color in autocomplete box in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012176/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-autocomplete-box-in-eclipse)