# How do I change hyperlink colors in Eclipse on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, eclipse, hyperlink, appearance

I use a dark color theme (oblivian) with Eclipse (Juno) and can't read the default blue hyperlinks. How do I change them? I went to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Active hyperlink text color and changed it to cyan but this did not work.

I've seen this question asked/answered for Linux but not Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a Windows system setting. The answer is actually contained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326826/changing-color-of-eclipse-links-in-quick-fix-or-eclipse-links-in-preferences-on) but for Windows XP.

To change in Windows 7:
Control Panel -> Display -> Personalization (lower left corner) -> Window Color (bottom middle) -> Advanced appearance settings -> In the Item dropdown choose Hyperlink then choose the color you want. I went with cyan, [much better](http://imageshack.com/a/img819/8601/23hy.jpg)!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for windows 10:
Create a class action law suit, to  Microsoft into making a "high contrast theme", in which only the link color is different.
0000FF or something like that.

(I´m serious. Doing this would allow for a universal setting of link-color, which wouldn´t need a change for all programming languages for all workspaces, if it even works for all of them.)